# Grails - Hibernate Column Readers/Writers

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-domain-class

I was watching a video presentation by Graeme Rocher about Grails (current and future versions), and he mentioned Hibernate Column Readers/Writers being available in version 2.4.

[Here's the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZH9n3s8Ai0#t=1526), which will drop you right to 25:26 where this topic begins.

Below is a screenshot I took. This feature would be helpful for me, but I can't find any documentation on it. Graeme mentioned it would be in the release notes, but I did not see it in there, and I can't find any other documentation online about this feature.

Anyone aware if this feature has been included, and if so, if any documentation exists on it? Thanks.

[image: Hibernate Column Readers/Writers]

Comment: pfff, don't waste your time, that Graeme guy hasn't a clue about Grails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be there in the code, but not in the documentation.  See the closed JIRA ticket [here](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11310) and the Git commit [here](https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/commit/96ce446da631a09b24424aa4bff965b1499e0f7c).  You can see an example of the usage in the test class [`CustomColumnReadWriteSpec`](https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/96ce446da631a09b24424aa4bff965b1499e0f7c/grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate/src/test/groovy/grails/gorm/tests/CustomColumnReadWriteSpec.groovy):

```
@Entity
class Name {
    Long id
    Long version

    String name

    static mapping = {
        name write:'UPPER(?)', read:'REPEAT(name, 2)'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jstricker - I've been looking up Hibernate Column Transformers, but can't find much on it - any ideas what options are available other than UPPER and REPEAT?

Comment: I think that is SQL and what is valid would depend on your database.

Comment: It seems like any functions provided by your particular database are fair game. Take a look at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapping-column-read-and-write for a bit more info.